# 404 not found Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

Hello I have the file on the folder url/v2/api/domain/*file.php* but when I try to do url/data/1, url/v2/api/domain/data/2. Say: 404 not found but if I put url/v2/api/domain/file.php/data/1 the format seems diferent and appear: Page Not Found Someone can see the mistake?

PD: Don't write duplicated because it isn't duplicated, just the title but the questions are differents.

> The page you are looking for could not be found. Check the address bar
>   to ensure your URL is spelled correctly. If all else fails, you can
>   visit our home page at the link below.
>
> Visit the Home Page

Code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('data/{name}', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $args) {
    // Use the PSR 7 $request object

    return $response->write("Hello, " . $args['name']);
});
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a .htaccess file in same folder as file.php. The content of the file are

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Then hopefully you can access the page without file.php

Comment: hm I'm trying to url/v2/api/domain/1 for example and it shows "The requested URL /v2/api/domain/1 was not found on this server." but now, if I put http://www.praktikum.secra/v2/api/index.php/domain/1 it shows correctly the value, but I don't want introduce "index.php"

Comment: Yes so for removing index.php you have to create above .htaccess